# Convert SQL Query (+JOIN) to Symfony Propel query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, propel

I have a sql query that works well on mysql (query + join):

```
select sum(pa.price) 
from user u , purchase pu , pack pa 
where (u.username = pu.username) and (pu.idpack = pa.idpack)
```

I want to use this query in my **symfony project (PROPEL ORM)**

How can I write it, please...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you [read the documentation](http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/#working-with-symfony2), it covers things like this.

As a guide for you, something like this (I don't know what you've called you models/relationships);

```
$query = UserQuery::create()
             ->select(array('total_price'))
             ->withColumn('SUM(price)', 'total_price')
             ->joinWith('Purchase', \Criteria::INNER_JOIN)
             ->joinWith('Purchase.Pack', \Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$results = $query->find();
```

Note that when adding a select method to your query, you will get an array result set, not a Propel collection.

Comment: Hi Friend, thank you for your reponse ...

After modification :

1- PAGE in Browser :  This site is inaccessible

2- Class php ; UNDEFINED CLASS CRITERIA

Comment: can you post your modified query you have built, and what page is inaccessible?